# Turning a string to a tuple of integers, which is added to a list of tuples

Tags: python, string, list, tuples, map-function

This is an assignment meant to teach the "map" function.

The user inputs a fraction such as "1/2" or "6/19", which is then converted from a string to a tuple of integers.

After all of the fractions have been inputted, a list of the tuples is returned.

I work off of that list to reduce, filter, and sort the tuples, but I'm not sure how to even start the problem and get the list.

Here is an example of what should work:

I need help on turning the fractions inputted:

```
Enter fraction: 1/2
Enter fraction: 6/19
Enter fraction: 20/8
```

into the tuples

```
(1, 2)
(6, 19)
(20, 8)
```

And after getting all of the fractions, a list of the tuples need to be returned

```
[(1, 2), (6, 19), (20, 8)]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def prompt_fractions():
    frac_list = []
    while True:
        my_frac = input("Enter fraction: ")
        if my_frac == "stop":
            return frac_list
        else:
            print(my_frac)
            frac_list.append(my_frac)

def main():
    frac_list = prompt_fractions()
    print(frac_list)
```

I tried using

```
my_frac = list(map(prompt_fractions, my_frac))
```

and

```
my_frac = my_frac.split('/')
```

but the first one required another argument, and I wasn't sure where to go with the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there; `my_frac.split('/')` returns a list of strings, not a tuple of integers:

```
>>> '1/2'.split('/')
['1', '2']
```

So you need to convert; `map()` comes in handy here:

```
my_frac = tuple(map(int, my_frac.split('/')))
```

This produces a tuple where each part of the split result is converted to an integer first:

```
>>> tuple(map(int, '1/2'.split('/')))
(1, 2)
>>> tuple(map(int, '6/19'.split('/')))
(6, 19)
>>> tuple(map(int, '20/8'.split('/')))
(20, 8)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was a simple fix, I just didn't know what that was.